# Form submit in ExtJS with POST method not working

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs, submit

I had my code as below:

```
            {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'myButton',
            handler: function() {
            if (Ext.getCmp('button').getValue().length > 1) {
                var mystring = Ext.getCmp('button').getValue();
                var url = 'myurl.com/test.cgi?search='+ mystring;
                var url_id = '2637;
                window.open(url,url_id);
            } else {
                alert("Lenth too small !");
                }
             },

             }
```

Now I have my code as below:

```
            {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'myButton',
            hander: function()
             {
                this.getForm().standardSubmit=true;
                this.getForm().doAction('standardsubmit',
                {url: 'myurl.com/test.cgi',
                standardSubmit: true,
                method: 'POST'}
                    );
            }

        }
```

My code was working fine when I had my code as first above but I will have limit on get method so it was crashing when I had long search string. Now I have post method but its doing nothing. If anyone can help me wheres problem or if you can tell me any other way to make the above code pass the form as post not url search=whatever like that so that it can take as long string as possible.

Comment: add `params:{search:'searchstring'}` to your config object. refer http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.action.StandardSubmit-cfg-params

Comment: what is submitted? What is receieved? what is the error?